# Oracle Apex Home URL issue- Fixed page not dynamic

Tags: oracle-apex

I was earlier facing problem with logging into application in apex. i later realised problem was with home url where page id was set to admin page, so any other user could not access it. I have set authentication an authorization schemes like pages specific to admin/manager/employee. 
However if i set any other page id in home url, all authorizations fail and nomatter which user i use to login, only that page shows up and other pages are not coming up.

Please help.

Comment: You're in the right direction, but we have limited information to help you. The home page can still be protected, but at least the login page still needs to be public. If you protect relevant pages + their links with authorisation schemes, you should be fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "However if i set any other page id in home url"?

Comment: Any page in my application, say its leave application and i set employee services page in home url. That page should be seen only by employee not admin. But due to being set in home url, it is seen by both admin and employee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vini,
Based on your limited info I'm assuming you have an app with pages for employes (10,11,12), pages for Managers (20,21,22), and pages for Admins (30,31,32).
My suggestion is to create an additional page (40) which you set as your home page.
On Page 40 have Pre-Rendering branches to the appropriate page based on Authorization. Authorization = Employee go to Page 10, If Authorization = Manager go to Page 20, etc.

Regards,
David